# iterate over an array and sum up all values with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, iteration

as the title says i'm trying to sum up using a for loop to iterate over an array.
can you give me some pointers as to where i'm going wrong here. i am returning the value NaN.

```
var total = 0;

function sum(input) {
    for (idx=0; idx<=input; idx++) {
        total += input[idx];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: variable total is not declared

Comment: You probably want to use `idx < input` in your `for` loop

Comment: thanks, yeah changing the <= to = seems to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `input` both as an integer, and as an array of values.  Probably you mean `for( var idx = 0; idx < input.length; ++idx )...`.

Comment: ahh thanks very much .. thats where i was going wrong .. this has sorted it now thanks very much

Comment: @dannywhite: be sure to take the other answers into account, too: your `total` is globally scoped.

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't need a loop to do this in modern browsers, you can use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```
var sum = input.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
}, 0);
```

Comment: nice functional style - not very newbie-friendly, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need ot declare total into function and also you need to declare idx. Another thing that instead of writing `idx <= input.length` you have to write `idx <= input.length - 1`. Since last index will be undefined.

Try

```
function sum(input) {
    total = 0;
    for (var idx = 0; idx <= input.length - 1; idx++) {
        total += input[idx];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

variable **total** is not declared!

```
function sum(input) {
    var total = 0;
    for (idx=0; idx <= input.length; idx++) {
        total += input[idx];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: It seems declared to me.  Only it's global, so the results will always grow.

Answer (score 0):

Problem which result in `NaN` is because of your array traversing array till end, rather than from indices `0` to `input.length-1`
Try this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/t9tfofxv/

```
var total = 0;
function sum(input) {
for (var idx=0; idx< input.length; idx++) {
    total += input[idx];
}
return total;
}
var s=sum([1,2,3,4]);
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable total inside the function, and also use input.length-1 to define the loop's range:

```
function sum(input) {
    var total = 0;
    for (idx=0; idx <= input.length-1; idx++) {
        total += input[idx];
    }
    return total;
}
```